# Reading a series of integers to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm new to arrays , i want to know if it is possible to fill the array using a for-loop with the scanf function , i made a first attempt but the program isn't working ( it is supposed to fill the array then print all the elements of it )

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void main(){
    int n,i;
    int table[10];
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        scanf("%d",table[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("\n%d",table[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return ;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare an array of size N, the elements are indexed from 0 to N - 1. From there, you need to pass the **address** of your variable to `scanf`, not the variable itself. Since you are using an array, this becomes very simple.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    scanf("%d", table + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
 scanf("%d", &table[i]);
```

Additionally the loop should start with 0, because indexes in C start from 0..N-1.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    scanf("%d", &table[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, array indexing starts from `0`.
Change `for` loop to

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {...}
```

and

```
scanf("%d",table[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &table[i]);  
            ^& operator before the variable table[i]
```

Comment: Done , the " & " operator :S i forgot it , and now i know how indexing is in C arrays . Thanx , thanx :D